# Update wrong data to the average of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of data that should be integers from 1 to 7. But the data contained mistakes and non-numeric data so I saved the column as nvarchar-type variable. Now I would like to estimate the wrong data by the average of the correct data, i.e. if the value is not from 1 to 7, it should be updated to the average of the data in the same column where the average has been computed on those cells that have value 1,2, 3,4,5,6 or 7. The estimated value can be a float. How can I do that in MSSQL? I tried

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(ky1 AS FLOAT)) FROM esimerkkikysely
WHERE NOT ISNUMERIC(ky1)=1 OR ky1 NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 7
```

but it returned 0.

Also,

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(ky1 AS FLOAT)) FROM esimerkkikysely
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ky1)=1
```

returns about 4.643.

Comment: The ISNUMERIC() function is extremely prone to difficulties; use another method if you can

Comment: Also: "But the data contained mistakes and non-numeric data so I saved the column as nvarchar-type variable." - that's not the way to solve your problem .You should stop bad data getting into the integer field in the first place.

Comment: I'm suprised this ran. Your WHERE clause appears to filter out numeric values. How can you convert a non numeric to float or find the average of it? You can't.

Comment: What result do you get if you remove the NOT in the where clause? Actually remove the whole OR clause as well.

Comment: `WHERE ky1 [NOT] IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')` would be far more accurate for pinpointing "errors" and getting correct values. `ISNUMERIC` accepts a ton of dubiously "numeric" values (like, say, `-$.`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Please, **PLEASE** do all your updates in a new column (I've called it `KY2` in the code below). The last thing you want to do is destroy the data you are working from, even if it is filled with errors.

```
UPDATE esimerkkikysely 
SET    KY2 = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(KY1)) IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
                 THEN CONVERT(FLOAT, KY1)
             ELSE (SELECT AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT, KY1))
                   FROM   esimerkkikysely e
                   WHERE  LTRIM(RTRIM(KY1)) IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')) END
WHERE  LTRIM(RTRIM(KY1)) NOT IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

I added in the `TRIM` as if the data import is as bad as you suggest, the chances of spaces being imported and messing up the comparison seems quite high.

Comment: I tried to do that but got an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: I missed the END clause. Try the above again.

Answer (score 0):

You only want the average of integers, between 1 and 7 inclusive, with tolerance to NULLs and strings, correct?

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (SuperColumn VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES ('2'), ('9874859'), ('JACKJACKSON'), ('1'), ('2'), ('2'), ('1'), ('3')

SELECT AVG(HisHighnessConverted)
FROM ( -- Do AVG only after filtering out problematic values.
    SELECT CONVERT(float, SuperColumn) AS HisHighnessConverted
    FROM @T1
    WHERE TRY_CONVERT(float, SuperColumn) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 -- Skips NULLs, failed converts, and successes outside of the BETWEEN range.
) AS T
```